# Confused by step in an inductive proof of arithmetical progression

Tags: arithmetic, induction

In the book "What is Mathematics?" there is a section that provides an inductive proof of the arithmetic progression.

Part of this proof is:

$\frac{r(r+1)+2(r+1)}{2}=\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}{2}$

I don't understand how you end up with the right hand side from the left hand side. Using the distributive law, I can come up with the following:

$\frac{r(r+1)+2(r+1)}{2}=\frac{(r^2+r)+(2r+1)}{2}$

But that seems a million miles away from $\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}{2}$.

Comment: Do you see the common factor of $(r + 1)$ in $r(r + 1) + 2(r + 1)$?

Comment: I didn't notice that common factor. What should I do with it?

Comment: Factor it out. ${}$

Comment: Also, you have an arithmetic error in your equation: the second term in the numerator on the right-hand side should be $ \ (2r \ + \ 2 ) \ $ .  If you now multiply out the numerator in the right-hand side of the first equation, you'll see that your right-hand side is equivalent, though not factored.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the question and the comments you are not used to factoring common terms:

The distributive law of multiplication over addition tells us that $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ (as presented in the second page of the book)

Let $a=r+1$, $b=r$ and $c=2$, $(r+2)(r+1)$ is then equal to $r(r+1)+2(r+1)$.

Generally speaking when you have the sum of different expressions with a common term you can factor it out